# Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-insert

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in D:\htdocs\sistemas\imobiliaria\admin\classes\imovel.php:603 Stack trace: #0 D:\htdocs\sistemas\imobiliaria\admin\classes\imovel.php(603): PDOStatement-execute() #1 {main} thrown in D:\htdocs\sistemas\imobiliaria\admin\classes\imovel.php on line 603 
>   **Query**

```
PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] = INSERT INTO `imovel`(
`tipo_imovel`, `tipo_negocios`, `codigo`, `cep`, `id_estado`,
 `id_cidade`, `id_bairro`, `id_rua`, `ibge`, `dormitorios`, `suites`,
 `nome`, `endereço`, `numero`, `valor`, `valor_condominio`,
 `valor_iptu`, `area_util`, `area_construida`, `area_total`, `comodos`,
 `detalhes`, `observacao`, `google_maps`, `imagens`, `imagem_capa`,
 `imagem_banner`, `lancamento`, `oportunidade`, `banner`, `ativo`,
 `data_cadastro`, `alerta` ) VALUES ( :tipo_imovel, :tipo_negocios,
 :codigo, :cep, :id_estado, :id_cidade, :id_bairro, :id_rua, :ibge,
 :dormitorios, :suites, :nome, :endereço, :numero, :valor,
 :valor_condominio, :valor_iptu, :area_util, :area_construida,
 :area_total, :comodos, :detalhes, :observacao, :google_maps, :imagens,
 :imagem_capa, :imagem_banner, :lancamento, :oportunidade, :banner,
 :ativo, :data_cadastro, :alerta ) )
```

**Valores das variáveis**

```
$tipo_imovel:2
$tipo_negocio:2
$codigo:211
$cep:87060-672
$estado:1
$cidade:1
$bairro:1
$rua_id:1
$ibge:0
$dormitorios:2
$suites:1
$nome:1111
$rua:Rua Pioneira Vergínia Maria Fecchio
$numero:899
$valor:122
$valor_condominio:22
$valor_iptu:44
$area_util:21
$area_construida:11
$area_total:12
$comodos:12441
$detalhes:a:1: {
    i:1;
    a:2: {
        s:2:"id";
        s:1:"2";
        s:9:"descricao";
        s:11:"piscina bla";
    }
}
$observacao:teste
$fotos:a:6: {
    i:0;
    s:43:"uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8932.jpg";
    i:1;
    s:43:"uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8a91.jpg";
    i:2;
    s:43:"uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8bcf.jpg";
    i:3;
    s:43:"uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8d18.jpg";
    i:4;
    s:43:"uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8e4e.jpg";
    i:5;
    s:43:"uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8f95.jpg";
}
$imagem_capa:uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde85f3.jpg
$imagem_banner:uploads/imagens/15233837575accfdcde8789.jpg
$lancamento:1
$oportunidade:1
$banner:1
$ativo:1
$data_cadastro:2018-04-10
$alerta:1
```

**Código**

```
if (isset($id)) {
    $cadastra_imovel = $pdo->prepare(''
            . 'UPDATE `imovel` SET '
                . '`tipo_imovel` = :tipo_imovel,'
                . '`tipo_negocios` = :tipo_negocios,'
                . '`codigo` = :codigo,'
                . '`cep` = :cep,'
                . '`id_estado` = :id_estado,'
                . '`id_cidade` = id_cidade,'
                . '`id_bairro` = :id_bairro,'
                . '`id_rua` = :id_rua,'
                . '`ibge` = :ibge,'
                . '`dormitorios` = :dormitorios,'
                . '`suites` = :suites,'
                . '`nome` = :nome,'
                . '`endereço` = :endereço,'
                . '`numero` = :numero,'
                . '`valor` = :valor,'
                . '`valor_condominio` = :valor_condominio,'
                . '`valor_iptu` = :valor_iptu,'
                . '`area_util` = :area_util,'
                . '`area_construida` = :area_construida,'
                . '`area_total` = :area_total,'
                . '`comodos` = :comodos,'
                . '`detalhes` = :detalhes,'
                . '`observacao` = :observacao,'
                . '`google_maps` = :google_maps,'
                . '`imagens` = :imagens,'
                . '`imagem_capa` = :imagem_capa,'
                . '`imagem_banner` = :imagem_banner,'
                . '`lancamento` = :lancamento,'
                . '`oportunidade` = :oportunidade,'
                . '`banner` = :banner,'
                . '`ativo` = :ativo,'
                . '`data_cadastro` = :data_cadastro,'
                . '`alerta` = :alerta  '
                . 'WHERE `id` = :id');
} else {
    $cadastra_imovel = $pdo-prepare(''
            . 'INSERT INTO `imovel`('
                . '`tipo_imovel`, '
                . '`tipo_negocios`, '
                . '`codigo`, '
                . '`cep`, '
                . '`id_estado`, '
                . '`id_cidade`, '
                . '`id_bairro`, '
                . '`id_rua`, '
                . '`ibge`, '
                . '`dormitorios`, '
                . '`suites`, '
                . '`nome`, '
                . '`endereço`, '
                . '`numero`, '
                . '`valor`, '
                . '`valor_condominio`, '
                . '`valor_iptu`, '
                . '`area_util`, '
                . '`area_construida`, '
                . '`area_total`, '
                . '`comodos`, '
                . '`detalhes`, '
                . '`observacao`, '
                . '`google_maps`, '
                . '`imagens`, '
                . '`imagem_capa`, '
                . '`imagem_banner`, '
                . '`lancamento`, '
                . '`oportunidade`, '
                . '`banner`, '
                . '`ativo`, '
                . '`data_cadastro`, '
                . '`alerta`'
                . ') '
                . 'VALUES ('
                . ':tipo_imovel,'
                . ':tipo_negocios,'
                . ':codigo,'
                . ':cep,'
                . ':id_estado,'
                . ':id_cidade,'
                . ':id_bairro,'
                . ':id_rua,'
                . ':ibge,'
                . ':dormitorios,'
                . ':suites,'
                . ':nome,'
                . ':endereço,'
                . ':numero,'
                . ':valor,'
                . ':valor_condominio,'
                . ':valor_iptu,'
                . ':area_util,'
                . ':area_construida,'
                . ':area_total,'
                . ':comodos,'
                . ':detalhes,'
                . ':observacao,'
                . ':google_maps,'
                . ':imagens,'
                . ':imagem_capa,'
                . ':imagem_banner,'
                . ':lancamento,'
                . ':oportunidade,'
                . ':banner,'
                . ':ativo,'
                . ':data_cadastro,'
                . ':alerta'
                . ')'
            );
}

if (isset($id)) {
    $id - bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
}

$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':tipo_imovel', $tipo_imovel, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':tipo_negocios', $tipo_negocio, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':codigo', $codigo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':cep', $cep, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':id_estado', $estado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':id_cidade', $cidade, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':id_bairro', $bairro, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':id_rua', $rua_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':ibge', $ibge, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':dormitorios', $dormitorios, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':suites', $suites, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':nome', $nomeImov, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':endereço', $rua, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':numero', $numero, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':valor', $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':valor_condominio', $valor_condominio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':valor_iptu', $valor_iptu, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':area_util', $area_util, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':area_construida', $area_construida, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':area_total', $area_total, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':comodos', $comodos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':detalhes', $detalhes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':observacao', $observacao, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':google_maps', $google_maps, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':imagens', $fotos, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':imagem_capa', $imagem_capa, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':imagem_banner', $imagem_banner, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':lancamento', $lancamento, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':oportunidade', $oportunidade, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':banner', $banner, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':ativo', $ativo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':data_cadastro', $data_cadastro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - bindValue(':alerta', $alerta, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$cadastra_imovel - execute();

if ($cadastra_imovel) {
    echo 'sucesso!';
}
```

Comment: O nome do placeholder está escrito diferente da forma que foi definido ou o contrário.

Comment: não deu certo de resolver o problema no final passamos para o modo old school com as variáveis diretas, é uma zona de baixo risco blindada contra invasores então não faz mal :D